# Gatling script works fine but prints j.l.d.LagartoDOMBuilderTagVisitor - Unclosed tag closed:

Tags: gatling

My script works fine but I a seeing below errors,  I am not sure what are these errors.  ch.qos.logback is the logger I am using.  Appreciate any help

```
    10:54:41.343 [ERROR] j.l.d.LagartoDOMBuilderTagVisitor - Unclosed tag closed: <p>
    10:54:41.345 [ERROR] j.l.d.LagartoDOMBuilderTagVisitor - Parse error: invalid character reference [@13593]
    10:54:41.345 [ERROR] j.l.d.LagartoDOMBuilderTagVisitor - Parse error: invalid character reference [@13896]
    10:54:41.346 [ERROR] j.l.d.LagartoDOMBuilderTagVisitor - Parse error: invalid character reference [@16187]
    10:54:42.467 [ERROR] j.l.d.LagartoDOMBuilderTagVisitor - Parse error: invalid character reference [@393]
    10:54:42.467 [ERROR] j.l.d.LagartoDOMBuilderTagVisitor - Parse error: invalid character reference [@479]
    10:54:42.467 [ERROR] j.l.d.LagartoDOMBuilderTagVisitor - Parse error: invalid character reference [@565]
    10:54:42.467 [ERROR] j.l.d.LagartoDOMBuilderTagVisitor - Parse error: invalid character reference [@651]
    10:54:42.467 [ERROR] j.l.d.LagartoDOMBuilderTagVisitor - Parse error: invalid character reference [@737]
```

Posting pom.xml information to review. Pom.xml file pasted below

```xml
       <dependency>
            <groupId>io.gatling.highcharts</groupId>
            <artifactId>gatling-charts-highcharts</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using latest Gatling 3.4.0? If not, please upgrade and update your question with the new logs.

Comment: Hi Stephane.  Yes I am using gatling 3.4.0.  please see my pom.xml in my question (updated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
10:54:41.343 [ERROR] j.l.d.LagartoDOMBuilderTagVisitor - Unclosed tag closed: <p>
```

This is a behavior change in Lagarto's latest version. I've opened a bug: https://github.com/oblac/jodd-lagarto/issues/5

Note: this bug is fixed in Gatling 3.4.1 (https://github.com/gatling/gatling/issues/3968).

```
10:54:41.345 [ERROR] j.l.d.LagartoDOMBuilderTagVisitor - Parse error: invalid character reference [@13593]
10:54:41.345 [ERROR] j.l.d.LagartoDOMBuilderTagVisitor - Parse error: invalid character reference [@13896]
10:54:41.346 [ERROR] j.l.d.LagartoDOMBuilderTagVisitor - Parse error: invalid character reference [@16187]
10:54:42.467 [ERROR] j.l.d.LagartoDOMBuilderTagVisitor - Parse error: invalid character reference [@393]
10:54:42.467 [ERROR] j.l.d.LagartoDOMBuilderTagVisitor - Parse error: invalid character reference [@479]
10:54:42.467 [ERROR] j.l.d.LagartoDOMBuilderTagVisitor - Parse error: invalid character reference [@565]
10:54:42.467 [ERROR] j.l.d.LagartoDOMBuilderTagVisitor - Parse error: invalid character reference [@651]
10:54:42.467 [ERROR] j.l.d.LagartoDOMBuilderTagVisitor - Parse error: invalid character reference [@737]
```

I have no idea what those are. Please provide the HTML content that generates such error.

Anyway, you should consider fixing your HTML which is malformed.